# DAX Threshold measure for percentages

Tags: powerbi, dax

I've spend hours trying different combinations of SWITCH(True...) and subtractions to correctly calculate this but cannot find a solution.

For example, I have the following thresholds for X amount of hours:

```
0-400: 10% 
401-1000: 17% 
1001-1300: 20%
1301-1675: 25%
1675-2500: 30%
2501 and above: 35%.
```

Please find below a simple example breakdown:

```
| Hours | 10% | 15% | 20% | 25% | 30% | 35% |
|-------|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|
| 1400  | 400 | 600 | 300 | 100 |     |     |
| 2600  | 400 | 600 | 300 | 375 | 825 | 100 |
| 3000  | 400 | 600 | 300 | 375 | 825 | 500 |


| Year | MonthNo | Hours | Amount |
|------|---------|-------|--------|
| 2020 | 8       | 970   | 48500  |
| 2020 | 7       | 1400  | 70000  |
| 2020 | 6       | 2600  | 130000 |
| 2020 | 5       | 3000  | 150000 |
```

The first 2 are easy to accomplish but I cannot cover all the rules. How can accomplish this in DAX and multiply by the correct percentage?

There is no percentage table, the percentage's would be applied to the amount as a rebate and then added up according to the thresholds. E.g:

```
+-------------+------+------+------+--------+-------+-----+-----+
| Percentages |      | 10%  | 15%  |  20%   |  25%  | 30% | 35% |
+-------------+------+------+------+--------+-------+-----+-----+
| Hours       | 1400 |  400 |  600 | 300    |   100 |     |     |
| Amount      | 7000 | 2000 | 5100 | 3000   |  1500 |     |     |
|             |      |      |      | rebate | 11600 |     |     |
+-------------+------+------+------+--------+-------+-----+-----+
```

Comment: Need to see your input data structure with your expected output from them. Also need to see how Threshold values are stored in your table.

Comment: @mkRabbani I've modified my question to add the requested info. Thank you for you time and consideration.